# How do I transform this javascript ajax code into query ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code seems really long - but i dont fully understand the jquery .ajax function to convert this code - My main problem is i dont know how to implement the responseText-bit

Any help is very much appreciated:

```
function getCategory(category){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("products").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","productlist.php?q="+category,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "productlist.php?q=" + category,
    success: function( data ) {
         $("#products").html( data );
    }
});
```

Or simply:

```
$("#products").load("productlist.php?q=" + category);
```

And of cause with the function wrap:

```
function getCategory( category ) {
    $("#products").load("productlist.php?q=" + category);
}
```